# Using multiple calipers in R package Matching

Tags: r, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am attempting to use the Match function from the Matching package to create a matched dataset on 4 variables. I want two of these variables to be exact matches and two to be within a set range.

I have the following code:

```
X <- cbind(tmpcomb$sexf, tmpcomb$dobyear, tmpcomb$municipality_code, tmpcomb$first_test)
colnames(X) <- c("sex", "dobyear", "municipality", "test_date")
Tr <- tmpcomb$Tr

#Define caliper for age within 5 years (see package documentation for caliper)
cal_age <- 5/sd(tmpcomb$dobyear)
cal_test_date <- 180/sd(tmpcomb$first_test, na.rm = T)
  
#match
tmp_matched <- Match(Tr = Tr, X = X, exact = c(0, 1, 0, 1), caliper = c(.001, cal_age, .001,  cal_test_date))
summary(tmp_matched)
```

I want `sex` and `municipality` to be exact, `dobyear` to be within 5 years, and `first_test` to be within 180 days. I believe that what I have written in for caliper is incorrect, though, as it is only doing exact matches. Could someone please explain to me how to use caliper in this setting, I think I must be doing something incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `exact = c(0, 1, 0, 1)` you are requesting exact matching on the second and fourth variables in `X`, which are `dobyear` and `test_date`, and requesting that exact matching **not** be done on `sex` and `municipality`. The calipers for `dobyear` and `test_date` are ignored because you are requesting exact matching on them. Change `exact` to be `exact = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)` to ensure you are requesting exact matching on the correct variables. The caliper for the exactly matched variables will be ignored so you don't need to specify `.001` for them (i.e., you can supply `Inf` and nothing will change).

Comment: Thank you!! This was exactly what I needed.